# confusion in one to one mapping in jpa

Tags: jpa-2.0, one-to-one, many-to-one

I am studying mapping in jpa and reading about `ManyToOne` and `OneToOne` mappings. The scenario is

- Many employees can belong to a department. i.e. ManyToOne between employee and department
- One employee is associated with one desk. i.e. OneToOne between employee and desk.

I"ve mapped these fields as follows

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "iddepartment")
private Department department;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "iddesk")
private Desk desk;
```

According to the book Mastering Java Persistence API, `OneToOne` mapping works as a unique foreign key. So in my example, one employee record should have specific desk id allocated. But even if I create multiple employees and assign the same desk to them, it gets inserted into the database. So what is the difference between ManyToOne and OneToOne here? according to me they behave the same way.

I am persisting entities as follows

```
/* Create EntityManagerFactory */
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("JPAExamples");

    /* Create EntityManager */
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    Employee employee;

    employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstname("pranil");
    employee.setLastname("gilda");
    employee.setEmail("sdfsdf");

    Department department = em.find(Department.class, 1); // retrieves
                                                            // department
                                                            // from database
    employee.setDepartment(department);

    Desk desk = em.find(Desk.class, 1); // retrieves desk from database
    employee.setDesk(desk);

    em.persist(employee);

    transaction.commit();

    employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstname("prasad");
    employee.setLastname("kharkar");
    employee.setEmail("dsfsdf");
    /* Now setting the same department for another employee which is fine because 
     * there is ManyToOne relationship betweem employee and department */
    employee.setDepartment(department); 

    /*
     * Here is my doubt. Even if I set the same desk for another employee. THe insertion 
     * is fine. Shouldn't the OneToOne relationship between Employee and Desk restrict employee
     * table having duplicate foreign key for both employees? 
     * 
     * If that is not true, then what is the difference between ManyToOne and OneToOne in this case?
     * */
    employee.setDesk(desk);

    transaction.begin();
    em.persist(employee);
    transaction.commit();
```

NOTE: I am not generating tables from entities.

So my questions are:

- JPA OneToOne annotation does not put the unique foreign key constraint on employee table. Is this the expected result?
- If this is expected, then why isn't there any difference between ManyToOne and OneToOne relationship?

EDIT: 
According to the answer provided, I've created this as a bidirectional relationship. It gives the same result.  Also, I've added `unique = true` also. That doesn't make any difference

In Desk class

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "desk")
private Employee employee;
```

and in Employee class

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "iddesk", unique = true)
private Desk desk;
```

Am I missing something serious?

Comment: Please add some more information. How is the OneToOne annotated in the Desk entity? How do you create and save them?

Comment: @kostja I've added some information about the question sir. OneToOne mapping is unidirectional here. SO there wasn't any need to annotate OneToOne in Desk class

Answer (score 0):

You have a unidirectional @OneToOne mapping. If you had a bidirectional @OneToOne mapping with the mappedBy attribute set on the "owning" side, the behaviour would be as expected.

E.g. in the Employee object

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
Desk desk
```

And in the Desk object

```
@OneToOne
Employee employee
```

Comment: If I add the unique key constraint in database, it works as expected. Is it necessary that I need to create bidirectional relationship? why can't unidirectional relationship exist without bidirectional relationship?

Comment: I've added as you suggested. It it not giving desired result.

Comment: My guess came from my own working code and might be misleading. In my code I have foreign key constraints in the database as well, but as they have been generated automatically from the java model, I didn't pay too much attention